# GROUP_CONCAT(SELECT * FROM table) is something like this possible?

Tags: mysql, join, group-concat

So I'd like to join two tables using an association table because table 'a' connects to multiple rows in table 'b', and I'd like to get all the results from each table that matches my a.value but the values from table 'b' should be concatenated somehow.

Right now my query looks like this:

```
SELECT *, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT g.group_name) group_name, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT g.group_profile_id) group_profile_id, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT g.group_publications) group_publications, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT g.group_followers) group_followers, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT g.group_ongoing_projects) group_ongoing_projects, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT g.group_finished_projects) group_finished_projects, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT g.group_members) group_members 
FROM projects_groups pg 
LEFT JOIN projects p on p.projectid = pg.projectid 
RIGHT JOIN groups g on g.groupid = pg.groupid 
WHERE p.projectid IN ($projectIds) 
GROUP BY p.projectid
```

The problem is that I'm not even selecting the half of the columns of the groups table but I'd like to get all of them. I could write down all the columns like above, but it looks really ugly and also i'd have to modify this every time I alter my table.

To further explain the issue a project can connect to multiple groups, and I'd like to get the project data with all the data of its groups. I could query the groups separately but that doesn't seem logical, cause i'd have to do it for each project (e.g. for 100 projects). So i get all the projects in one query and then a query for each project to get its groups. Or I could get the projects in one query joined with the association table and then get the ids from the association table and make a second query using these ids to get all the groups through the association, but I'm looking for a simpler solution.

Comment: Won't work either because different rows in table `a` could connect to the same row in table `b`, so they are not unique.

Comment: You should never `GROUP BY` a column in the child table, since that column will be `NULL` for any non-matching rows, and all the non-matching rows will then be grouped together.

Comment: To solve the problem of having to list all the columns, you could write a stored procedure that builds the query dynamically from `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS`.

Comment: Are you sure you want to use `LEFT JOIN` and `RIGHT JOIN`? If the columns in `project_groups` are foreign keys, they should always have a match in the master tables.

Comment: Thank you Barmar, I've corrected the mistakes you've pointed out. Building the query from `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` is kinda what i was looking for.

Comment: I think you should deny yourself access to "right join" this will make you more carefully consider how to construct a from clause and make your queries more maintainable. `WHERE p.projectid IN ($projectIds) ` will override all the outer joins anyway. try a re-write which uses FROM PROJECTS ....

Answer (score 0):

Pity there is no sample data nor expected result included with this question, however there are a few syntax issues worth mentioning. You start your FROM clause with this:

```
FROM projects_groups pg 
LEFT JOIN projects p on p.projectid = pg.projectid
```

This allows all rows from projects_groups even if there is no associated project. If there is no associated project then all projects.* columns would be NULL. However in the where clause you require this: `WHERE p.projectid IN ($projectIds)` which means that any NULLs from the projects table would be ignored and hence that LEFT JOIN is useless.

So as the projects seems to be the primary concern, use it with FROM and then join to the other tables appropriate to your needs. Now my guess is you can have a project without a project group (even if only temporarily) so you might use a left join here and so the query may look like this

```
FROM projects p
LEFT JOIN  projects_groups pg on p.projectid = pg.projectid
WHERE p.projectid IN ($projectIds)
```

but note you would only do that **if you wanted to list projects even if they have no associated project groups**. So making the assumption you do need that then continue this left join to groups as well:

```
FROM projects p
LEFT JOIN  projects_groups pg on p.projectid = pg.projectid
LEFT JOIN groups g on g.groupid = pg.groupid 
WHERE p.projectid IN ($projectIds)
```

If the assumption is wrong, then it will be more efficient to use inner joins:

```
FROM projects p
INNER JOIN  projects_groups pg on p.projectid = pg.projectid
INNER JOIN groups g on g.groupid = pg.groupid 
WHERE p.projectid IN ($projectIds)
```

Now we need to look at the SELECT & GROUP BY clauses. MySQL has historically allowed a very non-standard GROUP BY syntax and the default settings allowed a query like yours where only one column is listed to GROUP BY.

e.g. in the past this was allowed:

```
select p.* from projects p group by p.id
```

This is very bad practice and now current versions of MySQL now default to standard SQL syntax. Under standard SQL syntax rules you MUST SPECIFY every "non-aggregating column" in the group by clause. and so the example immediately above would produce a syntax error

e.g. you should always be precise about the group by columns

```
select p.id, p.name, count(*) from projects p group by p.id, p.name
```

So to help avoid syntax errors you might prefer to use a "derived table" like this:

```
SELECT
       p.* 
     , d.*
FROM projects p
INNER JOIN (
        SELECT
            p.projectid 
          , GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT g.group_name) group_name
          , GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT g.group_profile_id) group_profile_id
          , GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT g.group_publications) group_publications
          , GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT g.group_followers) group_followers
          , GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT g.group_ongoing_projects) group_ongoing_projects
          , GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT g.group_finished_projects) group_finished_projects
          , GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT g.group_members) group_members
        FROM projects p
        LEFT JOIN  projects_groups pg on p.projectid = pg.projectid
        LEFT JOIN groups g on g.groupid = pg.groupid 
        WHERE p.projectid IN ($projectIds)
        GROUP BY
            p.projectid 
        ) d on p.projectid = d.projectid
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing out my mistakes. You've probably figured out already that i have very little experience in writing mysql queries, so it's always great to find out what I am doing wrong. My initial question seems pointless now.